# How to make drag and drop work with primefaces TreeTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I need to reorder my tree. I am using the example provided in the primefaces [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/dragdrop.xhtml).

The drag and drop works for **p:tree** component. However when I apply the attributes to **p:treeTable**, it does not work.

How to make it work with treeTable? I have added the attributes draggable, droppable and dragdropScope to the p:treeTable tag, but it doesn't help.

```
  <p:treeTable draggable="true" droppable="true" dragdropScope="demo" 
      value="#{treeController.tree}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" animate="true">
    <p:column style="width:auto">
      <h:outputText value="#{node.title}" />
    </p:column>
  </p:treeTable>
```

Edit::
My issue is NOT that the tree does not reorder. My issue is that the items does not drag at all.

By dragging, I mean, when I click on an item and drag in the tree, some visual indicator showing the item can be placed anywhere else in the tree. See image below, where drag works. I have clicked on node 0 and dragged it to place between Node 1 and Node 2. This is from the primefaces showcase example.

[image]

Comment: Please always follow [mcve] rules. In this case post at least full treeController code and explain why it doesnt work.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the tree controller. The items in the tree does not drag, and that happens on the client side.

Comment: And thappens because it is just not 'natively' supported I guess See the docs for thst and check the issuelist for enhacement requests or be creative with drop zpnes

Comment: I'm also looking for the styleClass used for visualizing the dragged element. I'm using PrimeFaces without a predefined theme and die visualization is totally missing. DnD technically works if you add `<p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{delegate.processDrop}" />` as a child element.